# How can I modify my sshd process on an ubuntu server to log all passwords entered on failed SSH attempts by attackers?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, logs, sshd

If I have an Ubuntu VM exposed to the internet and multiple randoms try to brute force login to the SSH port each day, is there a way to modify the process that logs to `/var/log/auth` and also log the password used to attempt to log in with?

Comment: What would you actually gain  by seeing the passwords attempted? Compare this to the downside of your users mis-typing their passwords and then your logs have a record of almost-correct passwords for legitimate users.